# Maven javadoc plugin fix only existing javadocs

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am trying to fix javadocs for my project (mainly missing `@param` and `@return` values), and since there quite a lot of code to fix, I am trying to use javadoc:fix goal:

`mvn javadoc:fix`

Unfortunately, it generates javadocs even for classes that had none to begin with.
Is it possible to configure this goal to fix only existing javadocs?

I can't seem to find anything for this in [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html)

Or is there a better option besides this maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) plugin for eclipse. It has templates and modes that allow you to configure what parts of the javadoc to be updated. It is pretty easy to use.

> JAutodoc is an Eclipse Plugin for automatically adding Javadoc and file headers to your source code. It optionally generates initial comments from element name by using Velocity templates for Javadoc and file headers.

Comment: I am using intellij (and majority of my colleagues), that's why I'd like to avoid Eclipse, but if I won't find anything better, I will give this a try (in that case will accept it as an answer)

Comment: I looked into this plugin, and so far it does not seem to have the feature that I need. It adds JavaDocs to classes/methods that did not have any JavaDocs.